# Is it possible to have multiple languages accepted by a DFA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Is it possible to have multiple languages in a DFA? in my example in the image, I think the language L={w | w = 0x where x is {0}* } is accepted and the language L={w | w = 0x11 where x is {0}* } could be accepted as well. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Revisit the definition of the language a finite automaton *accepts*: it is the set of exactly the words the automaton has an accepting computation for. *All* these words, but *no others*. This set is always unique.

Here, the accepted language does indeed have *sub*sets

- $\{ 00x \mid x \in \{0\}^* \}$ and
- $\{  0x11 \mid x \in \{0\}^* \}$.

You will have to check if that are really *all* accepted words. This may be simpler to do after minimizing the automaton.

Comment: Especially since states $B$ and $E$ are unreachable and $ABE$ and $ABDE$ can be merged into one. From there it's easy to see that the language of this FA is $00^*(0+11)$.